# Range query with elasticsearch for string

Tags: elasticsearch, range-query

I am trying use range query with elasticsearch

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
             "order_no": {
                 "gte": "VM-0001",
                 "lte": "VM-0005"
             }
         }
    }
}
```

But elastic return no result. I found system have problem with string include `-` or `_`

This is mapping of that field:

```
"order_no" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "index_analyzer" : "str_index_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer" : "str_search_analyzer"
}
```

---

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "str_search_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
      },
      "str_index_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "substring"
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "substring": {
        "type": "nGram",
        "min_gram": 1,
        "max_gram": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "order_no": {
        "gte": "vm-0001",
        "lte": "vm-0005"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As per [the documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), in case of `string` fields, Elasticsearch uses a `TermRangeQuery` which as far as I know doesn't analyze the term to search for. This means that your range `VM-0001` - `VM-0005` searches for exact these terms. Whereas you have in your index something like `vm-0001` (lowercase).  So, either use:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "order_no": {
        "gte": "vm-0001",
        "lte": "vm-0005"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or add another field in your index where you keep the `order_no` as keyword without any lowercasing or nGram-atization.

Comment: :) Thanks you so much. I did it success.